# MySQL partial word match combining MATCH...AGAINST and LIKE as backup

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

The MySQL documentation for `MATCH...AGAINST` in boolean mode says something like "The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator." which means you can only use it for matching the start of a word. I want to be able to search as efficiently as possible and sometimes the words I'm searching for are partial words in the middle of the target string. I'm trying to avoid doing a full table scan when I don't need to.

Is there a way of combining the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax with a backup of `WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%`?

For example, I have the following table (with a bunch of field omitted for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE `tours` (
  `tourId` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tourName` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tourId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_tourId_tourName` (`tourName`,`tourId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to be able to search against both tourId and tourName in a single query, only doing a full table scan when I absolutely have to.

Is it possible to do something like this, where I combine the `MATCH...AGAINST` and the `LIKE`, without doing a full table scan:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tap.tourdetails
WHERE
    MATCH(tourId, tourName) AGAINST('dc10*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR tourId LIKE '%dc10%' OR tourName LIKE '%dc10%' ORDER BY tourName;
```

Currently, the above does a full table scan even though 'dc10*' is actually matched in the `MATCH...AGAINST`. I only want to use the `LIKE` (and required full table scan) if the MATCH fails. Possible? Alternative solutions?

Comment: The use of  `LIKE` with a wildcard at the beginning is generally going to require a full table scan.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking of there is a way to avoid it if the `MATCH...AGAINST` condition is successful.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"even though `'dc10*'` is actually matched"*: MySQL has no way to conclude from finding a fulltextsearch `match` that there won't be additional `like` matches. (And actually, it's the other way: `match against` seems redundant here (with these search terms), as `like` will find the same rows again that `match against` did, but not vice versa). You may want to explain what you mean by that exactly or what you are trying to do; maybe you are only interested in finding *any*, but not *all* results (but this would not be equivalent to your current search result).

Comment: I want to avoid a full table scan wherever possible because it's super slow. I want is as a fallback for when the match fails to find results.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are expecting to find `xyzdc10`:

- `MATCH` won't file `xyzdc10` but the `LIKEs` will.
- `LIKE` with a *leading* wildcard necessitates a full table scan.
- You are using `OR`.

Hence the table scan.

Instead, if you only want words *starting with* `dc10`, then get rid of `LIKEs` -- the `MATCH` does all the work, and does it fast.

`FULLTEXT` indexing breaks the column(s) into words, and searches for the words.  `LIKE` does not; instead, it has to scan each string.  No index benefits `LIKE` with an initial wildcard.